# How to Customize Ubuntu ISO to install programs, scripts and certificates on many machines

Tags: 14.04, iso, customization

I have been investigating different approaches to customize an Ubuntu 14.04 image so I can install scripts, programs and certificates directly onto computers. I need to image around 100 machines so I want to make this as efficient as possible to make the imaging of machines easy on the techs.

I have investigated Ubuntu LiveCD customization but I am not sure if this allows me to image many machines or if it just creates a bootable USB with persistent storage. Additionally, I am also investigating whether Ubuntu-Builder is capable of creating a custom ISO to eventually make a bootable ISO from.

If anyone has experience with either of these tools or approaches I could really benefit from the discussion and definitely a few pointers along the way!

**Update: I found the solution that I was looking for! Remastersys allowed me to put the correct files in the correct location and then clone the entire environment to an iso and image that to any computer!! I followed this guide; http://linuxhalwa.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-create-ubuntu-live-cddvd-using.html**

Comment: Don't. Puppet(master) is the way to go. see https://puppet.com/ A live dvd is only useful on 1st install on each machine. Look beyond that and you would be updating each machine manually again... puppet makes it easy to do this remotely.

Comment: @Rinzwind puppet.com appears to be a paid service...I was looking for a free/opensource solution.

Comment: No. They use the same model as mysql. Free unless you want the enterprise version. see https://puppet.com/product/puppet-enterprise-and-open-source-puppet "Chef" is similar. https://www.chef.io/chef/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution that I was looking for! Remastersys allowed me to put the correct files in the correct location and then clone the entire environment to an iso and image that to any computer!! I followed this guide; http://linuxhalwa.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-create-ubuntu-live-cddvd-using.html**

Answer (score 0):

For me [ansible](http://www.ansible.com) has worked great. Pretty simple to start, and it works well. It should also work for more massive server installations, but I cannot speak from experience here.

Anyway, as others commented, it is a much better approach than burning CD/DVDs....

Hope this helps,

Jeroen